# Why doesn't java.lang.Integer extend java.lang.Long?

Tags: java

It is possible to assign an integer value into a long variable.
It is possible to autobox an integer value into a Long reference variable. 
But it is not possible to assign an Integer object to a Long reference variable.

My view is an Integer / integer is a specific range of values that Long / long supports.

So the hierarchy should be Integer extends Long and Long extends Number.

Views invited.

Comment: It would make more sense if anything to ask the other way round, but the answer in either case is 'because that's the way they designed it'.

Comment: @EJP not really: if we just look at the number range every integer is also a long but not the other way round.

Comment: Interesting question.  But aside from the storage issue brought up by Eran, I'd guess that since the Java language treats the boxed classes specially, there's a possibility that making them subclasses could cause some other problems, such as making some expressions ambiguous that currently aren't ambiguous.  I don't know for sure that that's the case, but language designers do have try to look at corner cases and try to envision every combination of how the language elements could be used to make sure there are no problems.

Comment: @Henry That's exactly why it would make at least as much sense the other way around. The range of long extends the range of integer.

Comment: @EJP no, you can assign an integer to a long like you can assign an object of a subclass to a variable of the superclass but not a long to an integer. The "extends" in OO sense really restricts the set of allowed values. There are for example many more possible Objects than there are Strings.

Comment: @EJP I think `extends` has more to do with extending a class by adding methods, or by adding fields, not by extending the range of values.  A class that `extends` another class is supposed to maintain an "is-a" relationship.  A class that extends another class usually narrows down the parent class.  The possible values of the subclass are a subset of the values of the parent class; but since they're usually a subset where the values extend a specific property (e.g. `Dog` extending `Animal`), you can extend the class by providing methods tailored to that property.

Comment: Also note that [`int` is considered a primitive subtype of `long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Long` contains a `long` member (`value`) that contains the value of that `Long`.

If `Integer` was a sub-class of `Long`, `Integer` would either use that `long` member of the base class, which is wasteful (since `long` takes twice as many bytes as `int`), or ignore it and use its own `int` member, which would be even more wasteful (since in that case the `Integer` class would contain both the `int` member and the `long` member of the base class).

The boxed versions of the primitive types should be as efficient as possible (since you are forced to use them in some cases, such as `Collection`s, which can't hold primitives directly). Therefore any class hierarchy that would increase the storage of the `Integer` class seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is simple: If Integer extended Long, then instances of Integer would *be* instances of Long too:

```
Integer i = 0;
if (i instanceof Long) 
    // yes! oops... Integer would be a Long
```

Clearly, this is not the case mathematically and should not be the case.

Do not confuse types sharing a range of values with a case for having the types share a class hierarchy.

---

Discussions regarding storage etc are implementation detail and not relevant to the language design considerations this question is about.

Comment: Although I tend to agree that `Integer` shouldn't extend `Long`, I'm not sure why this is "clearly not the case mathematically", since every number that is an `Integer` belongs to the subrange of numbers covered by `Long`.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by your statement?

Comment: @ajb OK - emotive language removed, but 1) if anything Long could be considered an extension of Integer, not the other way around, 2) An Integer is not a Long. A Double can accurately represent every Integer value - does that make Double an Integer or visa versa? No. They are classes that share some of their value range, and they are Numbers, but that's all. The mathematical behaviour is different: Integer overflows where Long doesn't. Also, from a java language specification point of view, they are wrapper classes of the primitives, and autoboxing to specific classes is part of the JLS.

Comment: Ah, I missed the case that operators can return different mathematical results due to wrapping--that seems to be the clearest "mathematical" justification.  Yes, that by itself would seem to be a good reason not to use a subclass.  I think it would violate LSP to do so.